# How can I make this linetype in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I am currently drawing various map plots using ggplot.
I checked that the following axis linetype can be drawn on the x-axis and y-axis using the oceanmap package, but I couldn't find a way to implement this with ggplot.
Is there a way to apply the following linetype to the x-axis and y-axis in ggplot?

Comment: Looks non-trivial - this is not one of the built-in linetypes in R. I suspect there may be something that can be done by drawing custom rectangles

Comment: As @CalumYou said, that looks non trivial. Though, this is just like some custom plots with the outside panel designed with custom rectangle. For instance, you could have a fully black frame by adding :
`theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black")`

So if you can create a checkerboard rectangle based on the size of you ouput, you could use it as argument in `panel.background`.

Comment: I disagree that this looks non-trivial. Should be relatively easy, e.g., with `geom_segment`.

Comment: The most natural user interface would be through the theme, just like for grid lines, which are functionally equivalent. Implementing this type of borders would need changes to 'ggplot2' but not necessarily huge ones. Other approaches will get the plot done, but I think this would be the best solution in the long term. I suggest that you raise an issue at https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues even if the answer by @stefan  solves the problem in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, drawing this kind of axes in ggplot2 could be achieved via rects or segments. I went for `geom_rect`s as they allow for both a `fill` and a `color`. While doing such a legend is "trivial" in that it simply means to draw some rects in my opinion it isn't as it demands some (or a lot of?) data wrangling to set up the data for drawing the rectangles, ...

Basically I make

1. use of `geom_rect` to draw the segments of the axis,
2. use of `geom_rect` to draw the corners,
3. remove the default expansion of the scale,
4. added a separate fill scale for the rects via `ggnewscale`
5. Tweaked the axis ticks to have the same size as the rect border.

I tried my best to make my approach as general as possible but there is still a lot of space for improvement, e.g. in my approach you have to manually set the scales of the axes, i.e. longitudes and latitudes.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
library(dplyr)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

axis_black_white <- function(xl, xr, yb, yt, width = .05, size = .1, 
                        x.breaks = ggplot2::waiver(), y.breaks = ggplot2::waiver()) {
  if (xl > xr) { h <- xr; xr <- xl; xl <- h }
  if (yb > yt) { h <- yb; yb <- yt; yt <- h }
  # Top and bottom
  xmin <- seq(xl, xr - 1, 1)
  xmax <- seq(xl + 1, xr, 1)
  df1 <- data.frame(where = "b", xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = yb, ymax = yb - width)
  df2 <- data.frame(where = "t", xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = yt, ymax = yt + width)
  dfx <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(fill = xmin %% 2 == 0)
  # Left and right
  ymin <- seq(yb, yt - 1, 1)
  ymax <- seq(yb + 1, yt, 1)
  df1 <- data.frame(where = "l", xmin = xl, xmax = xl - width, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)
  df2 <- data.frame(where = "r", xmin = xr, xmax = xr + width, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)
  dfy <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(fill = ymin %% 2 == 0)
  dfxy <- bind_rows(dfx, dfy)
  # Corners
  dfc <- data.frame(
    where = c("tl", "tr", "bl", "br"),
    xmin = c(xl - width, xr, xl - width, xr), 
    xmax = c(xl, xr + width, xl, xr + width),
    ymin = c(yb - width, yb - width, yt + width, yt + width),
    ymax = c(yb, yb, yt, yt),
    fill = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
  )
  list(
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = x.breaks, expand = c(0, 0)),
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = y.breaks, expand = c(0, 0)),
    ggnewscale::new_scale_fill(),
    geom_rect(
      data = dfxy, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill),
      color = "black", size = size
    ),
    geom_rect(
      data = dfc, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill),
      color = "black", size = size
    ),
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"), guide = "none"),
    theme(axis.ticks = element_line(size = size))
  )
}

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma") +
  axis_black_white(-86, -74, 33, 37, width = .1, y.breaks = seq(33, 37, 1))
```

[image]